# Google Place API : Not able to get continent name from google place api android

Tags: android, google-places-api

How to get continent name from google place api android? It is not available in Place object or using geocoder.getFromLocation() method.I am using google place autocomplete.

Comment: it is not listed in geocoding API because continents are not   treated as part of the location.

Comment: Thanks @VladMatvienko. How to get the continent name. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://country.io/data/

This website has a lot of json-format country data that you could use to get the continent from an ISO-2 country code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cheers